# Что может означать 16#53# в качестве значения инициализации переменной в Аде?

Tags: типы-данных, типы

Дан следующий код на Аде:

```
procedure Main is
   type Element_Type is mod 2**8;
   Irreducible_P : Element_Type := 2#10001101#; 
   x,y : element_type;

begin
 x:= 16#53#;
 y:= 16#ca#; 
...
end;
```

В какой системе счисления переменные Irreducible_P, x,y инициализированы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В языке Ada число перед `#...#` это основание системы счисления, а символы между `#...#` это цифры в ней.

Тогда переменная `Irreducible_P` инициализирована в двоичной системе и равна `141` десятичному или `8d` шестнадцатеричному, что означает [Обратный перевод строки](https://unicode-table.com/ru/008D/) в Unicode.

`x` и `y` инициализированы в шестнадцатеричной системе счисления. `16#53#` это символ (байт) с кодом `83` десятичное или `'S'` в *ASCII*, а `16#ca#` -- `202` десятичное и вид символа зависит от кодировки. Скажем в *cp1251* (windows) это русская буква `'К'`, в *KOI8-R* буква `'й'`, а в *Latin-1* символ `'Ê'`.

(И в самом деле -- "если пристально вглядываться в текст на неизвестном языке, то постепенно его смысл начинает доходить до тебя".
Проверил в гугле и [вот тут](http://www.ada-ru.org/V-0.4w/part_1/ch_01.html) 
 в разделе Литералы это написано).

Comment: Благодарю за подробное объяснение!

Comment: @AndriiArtamonov Отметьте ответ галочкой, если он помог вам, это позволит системе считать вопрос решённым.